# Can I conclude that $E[X\mid \mathcal{F}]=E[X]$ implies $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Can I conclude that $E[X\mid \mathcal{F}]=E[X]$ implies $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$.I know that $X$ is normally distributed. (This would ofocurse on work if X is a constant since very constant is trivially $\mathcal{F}$ measurable)

Applying the definition of conditional expectation I get for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$

$E[X 1_A]=E[E[X]1_A]=E[X]E[1_A]$

Now if $X$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are independent we can claim that the product of expectations is the expectation of the product. But how to we prove independence in this case. **It appears to me that this condition doesnt imply independence. But I cant think of a counterexample.** 
Can somebody provide me a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has standard normal distribution then  $EX=0=E(X|X^{2})$, but $\{X,X^{2}\}$ is not independent.